# Adding any random attribute to python list or dict objects

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

This thing just came in my mind when i am doing some stuff related to oop.
If i have a class like this:

```
>>> class foo(object):
     def __init__(self):
         pass
```

Now we can set any random attribute for a `foo` instance like this:

```
>>> a=foo()
>>> a.any_attribute="any-value"
```

But why cannot we do this for other python structural objects such as list or dict objects:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> l.some_attribute="any-value"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'some_attribute'
```

I am trying to understand the logic and perspective behind this. My explanation is like this:-
Since all python objects have a `__setattr__` methods which is inherited from the `Object` base class.While we set an attribute of a python object using the syntax: `a.any_attribute="any-value"`,the `__setattr__` method is called. Since,my `foo()`, an instance of `foo` class has no restriction of setting only pre-defined attributes, it gives the freedom of setting any attribute.
But in the case of lists and other data structural objects, there must be some overidden behaviour for the `__setattr__` method which only allows setting of predefined attributes.

Am i right? 
If i am right,so what is the basic semantics behind this. Why we are not allowed setting any random attriubutes for these type of objects.
Are there any drawbacks or any violation of basic python beliefs, if this behaviour is allowed ?

I know that i might be wrong at certain points but since the question sounds interesting to me, I asked.
Regards.

**EDIT** - OK, i understood the answer,the fact that the class should have a `__dict__` method for adding any random attribute to its instance.But, the main question is that
**Are there any drawbacks or any violation of basic python beliefs, if this behaviour is allowed ?**

Comment: It's a good question and I'd upvote it, but it's a dupe

Comment: You cannot set attributes on `object()` either; what matters is that the object needs to have a `__dict__` instead.

Comment: @Claudiu , I understood why this is not possible but the main thing i want to know that is why setting of any random attributes of builtin python objects is not allowed. I want to know about  the perspective and beliefs of python behind this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, i have edited the post.Have a look once.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ; i have edited the post.Have a look once.

Comment: See the dupe; if all built-in objects had a `__dict__`, then so would the `dict` type, which means `__dict__` has a `__dict__` too, which would have a `__dict__`, which would have a `__dict__`... that's not a good idea. And a `__dict__` takes memory where most built-in types  wouldn't need this overhead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,thanks i understood this reason,i was just hoping that if there is something else also.But it's enough for me.Thanks once again.